# Firefox addon: Open a url in another tab

Tags: url, firefox, tabs

I am trying to make a context menu on a url to make it open that url modified in another tab(http://unvis.it/www.example.com). What am I doing wrong? I do not get any errors but the new tab will not open either.

```
exports.main = function() {
    require("sdk/context-menu").Item({
        label: "Open with Unvis.it",
        context:  require("sdk/context-menu").SelectorContext("a[href]"), 
        contentScript: 'self.on("click", function (node, data) {' +
                 'require("sdk/tabs").open("http://unvis.it/" + gContextMenu.linkURL);'+
                 '});',
        onMessage: function(msg){},
    });
};
```

Comment: Try to use a contentScriptFile instead of contentScript: it made your script more understandable and more secure than a string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

To do that you have to open the new tab in the onMessage function.
First on the click send a postMessage with the node.href value (the selected url) then use tabs.open with the parameter.

For more understandability I use two file, the main.js:

```js
var cm = require("sdk/context-menu");
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
cm.Item({
    label: "Open with Unvis.it",
    context:  cm.SelectorContext("a[href]"), 
    contentScriptFile: data.url('openWithUnvisIt.js'),
    onMessage: function(href){
        require("sdk/tabs").open("http://unvis.it/" + href);
    },
});
```

And the openWithUnvisIt.js in the 'data' folder:

```js
self.on("click", function (node, data) {
  self.postMessage(node.href);
});
```